# Small Caps from file with ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context

I am using a font which provides small caps as an additional font file. The fonts are available for ConTeXt, I checked this with

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list --all | grep Concourse
concoursec3     concoursec3     /Users/flyx/Library/Fonts/Concourse C3 Regular.ttf
[...]
concourset3     concourset3     /Users/flyx/Library/Fonts/Concourse T3 Regular.ttf
[...]
```

The c3 font is the small caps font, while the t3 font is the regular one. I am loading the font like this:

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [Concourse T3] [sc=file:concoursec3]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]
```

Now I am trying to use the small caps in text:

```
\starttext
  \ss This should be sans serif.

  \setff{smallcaps} This should use small caps.
\stoptext
```

While both lines are in sans serif, the second one is not in small caps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need the `\sc` font switch to get small caps, the `\setff` command is used to enable a feature in the current font.

Comment: @Metafox If I replace `\setff` with `\sc`, it still does not render small caps.

Comment: You have to set the full name for the small caps font, i.e. `\definefontfamily[mainface][ss][Concourse T3][sc=file:concoursec3regular]`.

Comment: That did it, would you post it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a different font by filename you have to use the complete name.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [Concourse T3] [sc=file:concoursec3regular]
```

Small caps are normally enabled with the `\sc` font switch, the `\setff` command can only be used when small capitals are a font feature where you can enable them for the current font.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [Concourse T3] [sc=file:concoursec3regular]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

This should be sans serif.

{\sc This should use small caps.}

\stoptext
```